# How to retrieve the jobId of job submitted via Dataproc from within the Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I want to get the jobId of the Spark job which is running from within the Spark Context.
Does Dataproc stores this info in Spark Context?

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc job ID is not available directly within SparkContext. You might need to call [Dataproc Jobs API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/list) to list all jobs associated with the cluster and find it out.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of patience, I found this solution (I'm using Dataproc image **2.0-debian10**, Spark **3.1.2**, Scala **2.12.14**).

In short, I noticed that you can get the Dataproc job ID by following these steps

1. acces the underlying **SparkConf** from the **SparkContext**
2. get the value of the **spark.yarn.tags** configuration
3. extract the id from such value with a little bit of string processing

I wrote this implicit class that extracts the ID as an optional value

```
implicit class RichSparkConf(protected val conf: SparkConf) {

  def dataprocJobId: Option[String] = {

    for {
      yarnTags <- conf.getOption(RichSparkConf.SparkYarnTags)
      dataProcJobIdTag <- yarnTags.split(",").find(_.startsWith(RichSparkConf.DataprocJobIdPrefix))
    } yield dataProcJobIdTag.substring(RichSparkConf.DataprocJobIdPrefix.length)
  }
}

object RichSparkConf {

  val DataprocJobIdPrefix = "dataproc_job_"
  val SparkYarnTags = "spark.yarn.tags"
}
```

As a rule of thumb, I usually try to take a look at all **SparkConf** key-value pairs and see if I can get something out of it that fits my requirement.
Hope it helps ;)